# Replace item in array of objects with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like this:

```
const myArr = [{id: 1, ...}, {id: 2, ...}, {id: 3, ...}];
```

and I have an object like this:

```
const myObj: {id: 2, someNewField};
```

I want to replace this new object for the one with the same ID in the original array, how can I do this?

I tried doing it like this:

```
const index = myArr.findIndex(item => item.id === myObj.id);
const filteredArr = myArr.filter(item => item.id !== myObj.id);

filteredArr.splice(index, 0, myObj);
```

It works but maybe there's a better way to do it

Comment: If you are wanting to replace it, find the index of where the old one is and then simply `myArr[theIndex] = <new object>`

Comment: You're already using splice, there's no need to create a filtered version beforehand. E.g. `myArr .splice(index, 1, myObj);`

Comment: `myArr.map((val) => val.id === myObj.id ? myObj : val)`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of finding the index and filtering you could always use `.map` to return a new array.

```
const myObj = { id: 2, new: 1 };
const myArr = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];

const newArr = myArr.map(v => {
    return v.id === myObj.id ? myObj : v;
});
```

It depends on what you would like to do if the item is not found in the array, as this will only replace.

Answer (score 1):

By better if you mean faster method, here is one,

```
for(let i = 0;i<myArr.length; i++) {
    if(myArr[i].id === myObj.id) {
        myArr[i] = myObj;
        break;
    }
}
```

This is faster than your method because we are using for loop instead of `.filter()` or `.findIndex()` which is slower than regular [for loop](https://towardsdatascience.com/javascript-performance-test-for-vs-for-each-vs-map-reduce-filter-find-32c1113f19d7).

If you mean the most compact then you can do this,

```
myArr[myArr.findIndex(item => item.id === myObj.id)] = myObj;
```

Note that this approach will fail if there is no item with the given object key.